# Nested routes browser url in flutter

Tags: flutter, url, browser, navigation

I have followed this [tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav). So far so good, nested routing works but the browser's url won't update when I navigate to a nested route. I understand browser url obeys the main Navigator. Is there a way to display nested routes too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you see in your browse url? a # ?

Comment: A #. Once Implemented the tutorial you get a #. Might it have something to do with? I have changed the url strategy with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of research I ended implementing Beamer nested navigation. You can find a reference of the feature [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/ma2qdo/complete_nested_routing_is_finally_here_beamer/). It works as expected and works great.

[Sample source code](https://github.com/slovnicki/beamer/tree/master/examples/nested_navigation)